# Issue reading CloudWatch Logs in .gz format after create_export_task in S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Created a Lambda to export the logs from CloudWatch on a schedule CloudWatch Event, that's all fine.

So the CloudWatch logs are now sat my S3 bucket in .gz format (that's what CloudWatch saves them as in S3 from create_export_task)

I now want to itirate that bucket and read the .gz files and convert the logs from JSON to CSV (don't ask) but the problem i have that any which way I try to read the files I keep getting the below result.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Not a gzipped file ('Pe')",
  "errorType": "BadGzipFile",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 28, in lambda_handler\n    content = gzipfile.read()\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/gzip.py\", line 292, in read\n    return self._buffer.read(size)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/gzip.py\", line 479, in read\n    if not self._read_gzip_header():\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/gzip.py\", line 427, in _read_gzip_header\n    raise BadGzipFile(&amp;#39;Not a gzipped file (%r)&amp;#39; % magic)\n"
  ]
}
```

Below is what i have been trying Opt 1, 2 & 3 all return the same result above.

```
from io import BytesIO
import json
import gzip
import csv
import datetime
import base64
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    logBucketName = event['s3BucketName']
    logFolderName = event['logFolderName'] + '/'

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    my_bucket = s3.Bucket(logBucketName)
    client = boto3.client('s3')

    for object_summary in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix= logFolderName, MaxKeys=1):

        obj = s3.Object(object_summary.bucket_name, object_summary.key)

        # opt 1
        content = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=obj.get()['Body']).read()
        print(content)

        # opt 2
        with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=obj.get()["Body"]) as gzipfile:
            content = gzipfile.read()
        print(content)

        # opt3
        bytes = io.BytesIO(obj.get()['Body'].read())
        gzipfile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=bytes)
        content = gzipfile.read()        
        print(content)
```

In the AWS document on Subscription Filters it states that

> The **Data** attribute in the Lambda record is Base64 encoded and
>   compressed with the gzip format. The actual payload that Lambda
>   receives is in the following format { "awslogs": {"data":
>   "BASE64ENCODED_GZIP_COMPRESSED_DATA"} }

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample

However I don't beleve this to be the case in CloudWatch logs that have been exported to S3 using the create_export_task as in S3 there are lots of .gz files and if you download and decompress the log file is readable without and Base64 decoding so that appears to be just for streamed logs.

Has anyone already solved this problem and share their advise?

Comment: Hey, did you find a way to do this?